# GVLMA, regression in R

Tags: r, regression

GVLMA in R makes an assetment on the linear model asumption using a global test. I need to store in a table whether the assumpions hold or not.

First i make a regression:

```
z<- data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(10)))
colnames(z) <- c("X","Y")
fit <- lm(Y ~ X, data=z)
```

Now i run GVLMA:

```
gvlma(fit)
```

The tables that comes out of this; How do I access this  (store it,use the values)?

Comment: Have you tried `myGVFit <- gvlma(fit); str(myGVFit )`?

Comment: Well.. I have not used this exact command... but it still leaves with me the question how do i get the info out?..somrething like myGVFit$GlobalStat4$Decision should return 0

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same need as you, this is how I did it:

```
gvmodel = gvlma(fit)
mtrx = summary(gvmodel)
```

Then I could just take what I needed from it like any other matrix.  For instance, the decision for Kurtosis (3rd row):

```
mtrx[3,]$Decision
```